# Which Angular dependent is causing a downgrade in npm install?

Tags: angular, npm

I have the following in my package.json file. This was originally generated using "dotnet new angular", and then I installed angular-bootstrap.

When I run "npm install", I'm getting 4.2.5 instead of 5.0.2.

How do I figure out which Angular dependent is causing a downgrade in npm install?

```
{
"name": "MyProject",
"private": true,
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "5.0.2",
"@angular/common": "5.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.2",
"@angular/core": "5.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.2",
"@angular/http": "5.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.2",
"@angular/platform-server": "5.0.2",
"@angular/router": "5.0.2",
"@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
"@types/chai": "4.0.1",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
"angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0",
"chai": "4.0.2",
"css": "2.2.1",
"css-loader": "0.28.4",
"es6-shim": "0.35.3",
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
"expose-loader": "0.7.3",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
"file-loader": "0.11.2",
"html-loader": "0.4.5",
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
"jquery": "3.2.1",
"json-loader": "0.5.4",
"karma": "1.7.0",
"karma-chai": "0.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
"preboot": "4.5.2",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
"rxjs": "5.4.2",
"style-loader": "0.18.2",
"to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
"typescript": "2.4.1",
"url-loader": "0.5.9",
"webpack": "2.5.1",
"webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.12"
},
"dependencies": {
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2"
}
}
```

Comment: I tried it and get 5.0.2 version of Angular. What's the output of `npm list @angular/core` if you type on terminal in project folder?